# Truncate date to start of the day in a given timeZone

Tags: date, java-8, timezone, jodatime

I am looking to truncate the date time to **start of the day** for the given **timeZone**.
If the current time is `Mon Aug 24 15:38:42 America/Los_Angeles`, it should be truncated to start of the day `Mon Aug 24 00:00:00 America/Los_Angeles` which then later should be converted to equivalent UTC time.

I have explored the methods provided by `Joda Time Library, Apache Commons Library and ZonedDateTime` but all of them truncate the date time in **UTC** and not to specific timeZone.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ZonedDateTime`. Use `toLocalDate()` on `ZonedDateTime` to get `LocalDate` then `atStartOfDay` on `LocalDate` with zone of `ZonedDateTime` instance to get the start of day.

Example:

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
ZonedDateTime startOfDay = now.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay(now.getZone());

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME;
System.out.println(now.format(formatter));         // Mon, 24 Aug 2020 10:41:41 -0700
System.out.println(startOfDay.format(formatter));  // Mon, 24 Aug 2020 00:00:00 -0700
```

Answer (score 1):

`ZonedDateTime` truncates in its own time zone. So it can be done a bit simpler than in the currently accepted answer (which is also a good and correct answer).

```
    ZonedDateTime given = ZonedDateTime.of(2020, 8, 24, 15, 38, 42, 0, ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles"));
    ZonedDateTime startOfDay = given.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    System.out.println("Truncated to start of day: " + startOfDay);
    
    Instant inUtc = startOfDay.toInstant();
    System.out.println("In UTC: " + inUtc);
```

Output is:

> ```
> Truncated to start of day: 2020-08-24T00:00-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]
> In UTC: 2020-08-24T07:00:00Z
> ```